# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, ts-node

I really went trough all the duplicates of this question, and no solution has worked. This is something different.

My project works perfectly on my local machine, but as soon as I run it on a server, I get this error: `> ts-node ./src/index.ts`

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

#### Nothing is run in the browser.

It is just server side *ts*

```
/root/ae-system/node_modules/rithmic-api/src/index.ts:1
import os from 'os'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:74:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1182:27)
    at Module._compile (/usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node-dev/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:568:25)
    at Module.m._compile (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-1410233924574671.js:69:33)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-1410233924574671.js:114:20)
    at require.extensions.<computed> (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-1410233924574671.js:71:20)
    at Object.nodeDevHook [as .ts] (/usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/hook.js:63:13)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
[ERROR] 13:49:17 SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

> **The error above occurs at a local npm module. The module was not installed from the npm registry but is a custom typescript project.**

The dependency was added at the main folder:

package.json

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "rithmic-api": "file:rithmic-api",
  }
...
```

I don't know if it is caused because of this.

My local npm and node versions are almost equal to the server versions:

`node is > 19`
`npm is > 8`

As for the Typescript configurations:

the custom npm module has

tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "outDir": ".dist/src",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "listFiles": false,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "types": ["node"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        // "declaration": true,
        // "rootDir": "sys",
        // "skipLibCheck": true,
        // "noStrictGenericChecks": true,
        // "noUnusedParameters": false,
        // "experimentalDecorators": true,
        // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
}
```

the main project folder has

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "outDir": ".dist/src",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "listFiles": false,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "types": ["node"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        // "declaration": true,
        // "rootDir": "sys",
        // "skipLibCheck": true,
        // "noStrictGenericChecks": true,
        // "noUnusedParameters": false,
        // "experimentalDecorators": true,
        // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
}
```

The main scripts to run the project are:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node ./src/index.ts",
    "dev": "tsnd --cache-directory \".cache\" --watch \"./rithmic-api/src, ./strategy\" --respawn --clear --no-warnings ./src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
```

Comment: `{
  "type": "module",
  // ️ rest ...
}` Can you try to add this in your package.json?

Comment: i tried this from many solutions I read. I have two `package.json` in both I get an error If i add this field.

Comment: the project works well on my desktop. It does not work on my server.

Comment: Did you try to remove node_modules folder and install the packages all again? `rm -rf ./node_modules`

Comment: yes and now the project broke on both machines. It seems that my local dependency rithmic-api is no longer copied as a link to a folder, it is now copied inside in its typescript form

Comment: rithmic-api is a local npm package in the root folder

Comment: i fixed the problem using these instructions. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-a-local-module-using-npm/

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by myself or some change in npm where local packages are not linked, but installed

I used these instructions to fix the issue:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-a-local-module-using-npm/

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem of typescript not finding your `tsconfig.json` file. Your config looks fine. Something that I am wondering is why don't you build everything into the `dist` folder and just deploy the `dist` folder to your server this way the modules are build into the `dist`? I think `node` running `javascript` is faster that `ts-node` running `typescript`.

Fixed by OP after discussion below:
`i fixed the problem using these instructions. geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-a-local-module-using-npm`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250459/discussion-on-answer-by-lars-vonk-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outsi).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and what I did was just `tsc fileName.ts` and then I just used the js version, cause I think the file is being used as a ts file and it's not getting modified to a js file, that's why I was getting that error in my case. `ts-node-dev` should do that job but it didn't.